# Can I have 2 independent installations of InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

I want to run two separate and independent instances/installations of InfluxDB on the same machine (running on ubuntu). They should have different endpoints.

Is it possible? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just provide required configuration in corresponding `influxdb.conf` for each installation. The following attributes must be reconfigured to reference different targets:

Different data, wal and meta storage directories:

```
[data]
  # The directory where the TSM storage engine stores TSM files.
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/data"

  # The directory where the TSM storage engine stores WAL files.
  wal-dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/wal"

[meta]
  # Where the metadata/raft database is stored
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/meta"
```

Different HTTP (UDP) ports:

```
[http] 
  # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true

  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  bind-address = ":8086"

[[udp]]
  enabled = false
  bind-address = ":8089"
```

Also take a look, at other configuration settings to see if they not conflict.